# Blazor WebAssembly AuthenticationService.js not calling openid-configuration on certain redirect

Tags: asp.net, authentication, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor wasm hosted model but I am having difficulty with authentication. So the basic flow of the authentication works perfectly, in a sense where if I copy the URL and paste it in the browser, it works as expected. However, if it is being redirected, especially from google services (like search console or youtube live chat), the AuthenticationService.js for some reason don't call the openid-configuration.

Here is how to recreate it:

1. Normal Flow

- Open a new tab in the browser
- Inspect the element and go to the network tab before going to the page
- Copy and paste this url into the browser: https://bagibagi.co
- Visit the page
- You should see openid-configuration being called and if you go to the initiator section, if you look something like this
  [image]

2. Redirect flow (where the authentication is not working)

- visit this live URL: https://www.youtube.com/live/4LaFQKNpth0?si=HJ_Xon-PJlWfPKhG
- click on the link that is in the live chat box
- inspect the element once redirected and go to the network tab
- refresh the page to see the whole request
- This shouldn't contain any openid-configuration made in the network tab (when it should), and if you go to the initiator tab of the network request, you'll see this
  [image]

Please also find the code below that I used to implement the authentication on the backend side

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "BagiBagiCors", policy => policy.WithOrigins("https://bagibagi.co").AllowCredentials().WithMethods("GET"));
});


builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser,IdentityRole>(options => {
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
    options.Tokens.ProviderMap.Add("CustomEmailConfirmation",
            new TokenProviderDescriptor(
                typeof(CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>)));
    options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = "CustomEmailConfirmation";
})
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationClaimsPrincipalFactory>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddTransient<CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>>();
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "somecert.pfx"), "somepassword");

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        options.IssuerUri = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServer:IssuerUri");
    })
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddSigningCredential(cert);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt()
    .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
    {
        googleOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["google:client-id"];
        googleOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["google:client-secret"];
        googleOptions.CallbackPath = "/signin-google";
        googleOptions.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        googleOptions.Scope.Add("openid");
        googleOptions.Scope.Add("profile");
        googleOptions.Scope.Add("email");
    });

builder.Services.PostConfigure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/account/logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/account/AccessDenied";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

I've been searching for questions like this online but couldn't find any answer, so any attempt in helping me solve this problem will be extremely appreciated. Thank you!